# No HTTPS access in Genymotion emulator after configuring proxy

Tags: proxy, android-emulator, genymotion

emulator certificate is installed system store using "tmpfs” Manual method
https://pswalia2u.medium.com/install-burpsuites-or-any-ca-certificate-to-system-store-in-android-10-and-11-38e508a5541a

proxy configured by following command

```
adb -s 127.0.0.1:5555 shell settings put global http_proxy localhost:3333
```

```
adb -s 127.0.0.1:5555 reverse tcp:3333 tcp:8081
```

videos

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1565SgozUA_YLpl94BLitTbZAg67ommuA/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10pQqmaRgnv9Gn6yaF04FEtRJ67xuZ_mN/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17b_SdULvOR2pJxRi4zznZPeX4XesYgsm/view?usp=sharing

I have read many blogs, but none of them have been helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.